# Distribution of areas of Voronoi cells on a sphere

Tags: probability-distributions, area, spheres, tessellations, voronoi-diagram

I have two sets of, respectively, *N* and *M* points, which are independently, randomly allocated on a sphere. I consider the Voronoi tessellation of the sphere by the *N* points, and I want to find how many of the other *M* points are on average in a Voronoi cell, and the standard deviation (or variance) of this number. As I am drawing point locations from a uniform distribution, I am thinking of looking at the statistics of Voronoi cell areas (first two moments), and then estimate accordingly the mean and variance of the density of points out of the *M* ones per cell. However, it looks like there is no analytical estimation of the PDF for cell area distribution for the spherical Voronoi tessellation. Any reference/suggestion that comes to mind? Otherwise, any alternative approach for the solution of my problem? I stress that I am looking for analytical solutions.

Comment: How do you build your spherical Voronoi cells ? Using $\mathbb{R}^3$ distance or by arc (= geodesic) distance ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am sticking to the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$ mostly because, I have that easily implemented in the `scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi` method.

Comment: Are you aware of the "Lambert cylindrical equal area projection", as described p. 5 of this document ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach the URL of the document  : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.768.5895&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. I did not know this mapping. I am going to see if it can be used. I will follow up.